# "rosrun rgbdslam rgbdslam" symbol lookup error, fuerte

Tags: slam, navigation, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

after compiling rgbdslam successfully, I tried to start rgbdslam. All I got was a "symbol lookup error":

```
/home/robot/ros/rgbdslam/bin/rgbdslam: symbol lookup error: /home/robot/ros/rgbdslam/lib/libgicp.so: undefined symbol: gsl_multimin_fdfminimizer_vector_bfgs2
```

After searching the web for a while I found a related topic [here](http://gdwarner.blogspot.co.at/2009/03/c-runtime-symbol-lookup-error.html).

So I changed the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to /opt/ros/fuerte/lib:/usr/lib and exported it but I didn't fix the error.

GSL Version:libgsl0ldbl 1.15+dfsg-1build1
ROS Fuerte
Ubuntu 12.04

Can somebody help me?

Cheers!
Georg

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43761/%22rosrun-rgbdslam-rgbdslam%22-symbol-lookup-error,-fuerte/) by [marvin](https://answers.ros.org/users/3201/marvin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2012-09-12

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) on 2012-09-13**:
are these packages installed "gsl-bin libgsl0-dev"?

**Comment by [marvin](https://answers.ros.org/users/3201/marvin/) on 2012-09-13**:
yes, they are installed.

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2012-09-24**:
weird, that is a runtime error or a linker error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Could be that you need to deinstall ros-fuerte-libg2o (and rebuild rgbdslam)

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2013-01-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0